# Is there a way to put a python script in a website?

Tags: python, html, cgi

I am new to HTML, and was doing a project where I asked input from a user, ran a script and displayed the output. I wrote the script in python and I have the website code in HTML. I was wondering how I can somehow get the input on the website, run the python script, and display the output on the website. All of the code for the script and the website is below.

Python Script:

```
def transcribe(phrase):
transcription = ""
for letter in phrase:
    if letter in "Tt":
        transcription = transcription + "A"
    elif letter in "Aa":
        transcription = transcription + "U"
    elif letter in "Cc":
        transcription = transcription + "G"
    elif letter in "Gg":
        transcription = transcription + "C"
    else:
        transcription = transcription + letter
return transcription

print(transcribe(input("Enter Your DNA string: ")))
```

HTML Website Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Codon Converter</title>
    </head>

<style>
/* Style the body */
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Header/Logo Title */
.header {
  padding: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #33A5FF;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

/* Page Content */
.content {padding:20px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h1>Transcribe DNA to mRNA</h1>
  <p>This website will take DNA and transcribe it into mRNA</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="DNA">DNA:</label><br>
      <p></p>
  <input type="text" id="DNA" name="DNA" value=""><br>
      <p></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: That's called an app

Comment: You need [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally don't do work for other people, but I needed to test new development environment, so here it is:

[RNATranscriptase](https://github.com/Forinil/RNATranscriptase)

A Flask-based Python webapp that uses your script to transcribe DNA to mRNA. Also uses jQuery to post data and Boostrap for styling.

Comment: Thank you so much, can I use this?

Comment: That depends on what you want to use it for. I’d start by cloning the repository and looking over the code. Maybe get the app up and running - even if you do not have Docker, you can still use instructions from Dockerfile to run the app locally.

Comment: Yes, I have the app up and running. I was more so wondering if I have the right to put this app online under my name. Would that be okay? Also, I accepted your answer sorry for not doing so earlier.

Comment: I did put a LICENSE in the repository. Feel free to familiarize yourself with it. The gist is that you can do whatever you want with it as long as you clearly state that I wrote it.

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you, but I wanted to add another script to the site and cannot figure out how you did it, so if it's not too much work can you explain how you were able to do it.

Comment: Here's documentation for jQuery (which I used for the frontend): https://api.jquery.com/ and here's one for Flask (used in the backend): https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/. And here's a link to a really comprehensive tutorial of Flask: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world. Hope those help.